# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(asyncId)' of null

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have a node.js based express-server which should handle some database-operations. Currently, I try to GET some information of my SQL-Database, based on a provided email. While executing the operation below, I run into a strange error.

```
app.get("/character/:account_email", jsonparser, (req, res) => {
    database.query("SELECT account_email, character_name, creation_date, blood, money, experience_points, age, is_alive, place_name FROM vmpr_character WHERE account_email = ?", [req.params.account_email], (error, response, fields) => {
        res.set({ "Content-Type": "application/json" });
        if (!error) {
            res.status(201);
            res.write(JSON.stringify(response[0]));

            database.query("SELECT attribute_name, level FROM character_attributes JOIN vmpr_character USING (account_email) WHERE character_attributes.account_email = ?", [req.params.account_email], (error2, response2, fields2) => {
                if (!error2) {
                    res.write(JSON.stringify(response2));
                } else {
                    res.status(502);
                }
            });
        } else {
            res.status(404);
            res.write(JSON.stringify(dummy));
        }
        res.end();
    });
});
```

---

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(asyncId)' of null
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:636:24)
    at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:630:10)
    at Query.database.query [as _callback] (/Users/nightmare/vmpr/components/database_server/NodeJS/server.js:103:10)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/Users/nightmare/vmpr/components/database_server/NodeJS/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:86:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/Users/nightmare/vmpr/components/database_server/NodeJS/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:137:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (/Users/nightmare/vmpr/components/database_server/NodeJS/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:121:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/nightmare/vmpr/components/database_server/NodeJS/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:280:23)
    at Parser.write (/Users/nightmare/vmpr/components/database_server/NodeJS/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:75:12)
    at Protocol.write (/Users/nightmare/vmpr/components/database_server/NodeJS/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/nightmare/vmpr/components/database_server/NodeJS/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103:28)
```

The same error occours while POSTing some data into the same DB. The server crashes on both POST and GET, even while the data provided are still saved normally. Executing these queries in mysql directly gets me the correct results. All logs are fine.

EDIT: 
* With the provided update, the error is gone, the new error is much better to handle.
* Everything is fine now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in [node v8.2.1](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/14399) which should be landing today.